# Laravel Valet not serving jpeg files with no extension

Tags: laravel, laravel-valet, caddy, caddyfile

Laravel Valet serving jpeg files with no extension with wrong size and changed checksum of course.
I'm posting information about an example file, the file with `.0` at the end is downloaded through valet.

```
$ls -la
f2b40f33d19b147bc8d0e88f4b8c489e35c165dd
-rw-r--r--   23905
f2b40f33d19b147bc8d0e88f4b8c489e35c165dd.0
-rw-r--r--   23750
```

```
$ls -la
$ md5 f2b40f33d19b147bc8d0e88f4b8c489e35c165dd
MD5 (f2b40f33d19b147bc8d0e88f4b8c489e35c165dd) = 9b5d3e104764e4b4c2b9e942704091f1
$ md5 f2b40f33d19b147bc8d0e88f4b8c489e35c165dd.0
MD5 (f2b40f33d19b147bc8d0e88f4b8c489e35c165dd.0) = 944e47ce0ccd4da18b7761af0e5f0226
```

I tried adding a mime to CaddyFile but it seems caddy does not support mime for files with no extension. I tried the following:

```
mime . image/jpeg
mime .* image/jpeg
mime * image/jpeg
```

Same file with a `.jpeg` extension is OK, what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valet uses `mimes.php` in `ValetDriver.php` to determine the right content type based on the file extension:

```
...
"jpeg" => "image/jpeg",
"jpg" => "image/jpeg",
"jpe" => "image/jpeg",
...
```

you can add the empty extension there, to serve everything without extension as image/jpeg

```
"" => "image/jpeg"
```

However, Valet isn't supposed to server files with empty extension, you get the notice which breaks the image

```
Notice: Undefined index: extension in ...cli\drivers\ValetDriver.php on line 121
```

As a quick hack you can change the line #121 in `~/.composer/vendor/cli/drivers/ValetDriver.php` to suppress the notice

```
@$extension = pathinfo($staticFilePath)['extension'];
```

Comment: Content-Type is now `image/jpeg` but the file is still broken.

Comment: can you share the file? I have valet to test

Comment: sure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1_SMS-8hKqydF9keWI4UUthcmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here is the file served by my valet
https://e1f2c2a7.ngrok.io/f2b40f33d19b147bc8d0e88f4b8c489e35c165dd 
I've updated my answer

Comment: thanks! what do you think is wrong with my setup? any logs I could check?

Comment: I think, it's all good, just suppress the notice with `@` in that file, see my update

Comment: thank you, should I create an issue on valet's github?

Comment: not sure if this is an issue or a feature, imagine someone wants to server files with no extensions as png, this is something specific to your case